# Ext.extend vs Ext.override?

Tags: extjs

What is the difference between Ext.extend and Ext.override? In java, you extend a class and you override its methods. But looking at syntax, it seems in extjs, you can both extend a class and override a class

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`Ext.extend` gives you a new class basing on existing one.

`Ext.override` modifies existing class without creating a new one.

It's not something specific to ExtJS. It's how JavaScript's prototype-based object model works. It's quite different from what you're used to in Java. ExtJS just adds these two utility methods to make it a bit easier to use.

Comment: So Ext.override has no equivalent in java?

Comment: this is not entirely true, you can override methods any existing class when you create an instance of it as an anonymous inner class. `ArrayList al = new ArrayList() { public void add(Object o) { // override }` for example. This is the same thing in spirit since it is still an `ArrayList` as far as any client is concerned.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Interesting! I've very little experience with Java, so I didn't know this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mchl has already answered to your query.

I just want to add, for adding features to ExtJs involves these four ways:

1. Extend
2. Override
3. Plugin
4. Sequence/Intercept

Please refer to this link for detail information:

http://www.slideshare.net/VinylFox/four-ways-to-add-features-to-ext-js

Comment: In ExtJS 5 we have `Ext.Function.interceptBefore` instead Intercept
and `Ext.Function.interceptAfter` instead Sequence.

Comment: Thanks for adding up the information, I didn't looked @ExtJs 5 that time.